# Non-linear Diffusion Equation

Tags: differential-equations, diffusion, non-linear-systems

I'm currently trying to solve the equation $$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{D}{C}\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right),
$$ where D is a constant and $C \equiv C(x,t).$ The initial condition on $C$ is $C(x,0)=N_0 \delta(x).$ So far I've tried solving either it using its Fourier transform or by treating it similarly to the heat equation (http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/apm346h1/20129/L9.html), but my attempts have been unsucsessful. Any idea on how to find a solution? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You will also a need two boundary conditions: the PDE is second order in $x$.

Comment: This is not a question about physics, more appropriate to mathematics stackexchange.