# How to numerically solve non-linear 1D diffusion equation in time-domain?

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, simulations, diffusion

The equation to be solved is this:

$$\frac{\partial H_y(x,t)}{\partial t}=\left(\frac{1}{\sigma\:\mu(H_y)}\right)\frac{\partial^{2}{H_y(x,t)}}{\partial{x^{2}}}$$

But note that the magnetic permeability $\mu$ is dependent on the magnetic field (by an $B\times H$ curve).

I could solve this equation for the linear case (when the magnetic permeability is constant) using a numerical integration scheme provided by Professor Langtangen ([available here](http://hplgit.github.io/num-methods-for-PDEs/doc/pub/diffu/sphinx/._main_diffu001.html#:%7E:text=where%20u(x%2Ct),t%3D%CE%B1uxx.)). I published it in a paper together with some analysis to make it know by others electrical engineers interested on this topic ([available here](https://ietresearch.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1049/iet-epa.2020.0275)). The paper contains more details on the problem. Splitting the problem in $n$ sections, the numerical integration scheme that works for the linear case is:
$$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1+2F & -F & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
-F & 1+2F & -F & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -F & 1+2F & -F & 0\\ 
\vdots & 0 & -F & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1+2F
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
H_{1}^{i}\\ 
H_{2}^{i}\\ 
H_{3}^{i}\\ 
\vdots\\ 
H_{n}^{i}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
H_{1}^{i-1}\\ 
H_{2}^{i-1}\\ 
H_{3}^{i-1}\\ 
\vdots\\ 
H_{n}^{i-1}
\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
with $i$ being the counter for the time instant and
$$\begin{align}
F=\frac{\Delta t}{{\Delta x}^{2}}\,\frac{1}{\sigma\:\mu}\label{eq3}
\end{align}$$

However, I never managed to solve it for the non-linear case. I tried to find some hints here on Stack Exchange in Mathematica and here in Physics, but the non-linear diffusion equation question typically do not get answers ([as here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/688158/)). Or I couldn't understand due to my math limitations.

The boundary conditions are $H_y$ imposed (external field) and $H_n$ can be unconstrained (in the linear case the $H_n=0$ could be assumed, but if the metallic plate can saturate, this condition is not valid anymore). One alternative I see could be to constrain the total flux through the plate.

An author, Sergey Zirka, could solve it using Taylor Expansion, I suppose. I tried to use that, but it didn't work for me as well. The paper is [available here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265911312_Accounting_for_the_Influence_of_the_Tank_Walls_in_the_Zero-Sequence_Topological_Model_of_a_Three-Phase_Three-Limb_Transformer) and the solution seems to be the Eq2. Fig5 is the type of result I'm looking for.

If anyone can shed light on the topic or point to a solution, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "I never managed to solve it for the non-linear case." mean? Did you get errors running it? You never write code for it? Something else?

Comment: I tried to code it or solve in excel, but the solution diverged or was wrong. I'll try to ellaborate better my attempts.